# Derivative in the sense of distributions

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

I have a question regarding calculating the derivative in the distribution sense of the following function:

$$
f(x) = \frac{d^2 }{d x^2}|\cos|x||
$$

Maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks,
Daniel.

Comment: Note that $ \cos(|x|) = \cos(x) $ as $ \cos $ is an even function.

Comment: Yes. Then I should write the integral of the function like a sum on R?

Comment: The distributional derivative of a *continuous* and *piecewise $C^1$* function "equals" the classical derivative. If you have a piecewise $C^1$ function with jump discontinuities, the distributional derivative will be the sum of the classical derivative and $\delta$:s coming from the jumps.

Answer (score 1):

You must guess which is the derivative. Since $|\cos x|$ is differentiable almost everywhere, the pointwise derivative should work. Then you must verify that the pointwise derivative satisfies the definition of weak derivatives.